# ng-hide based on scope values

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I want to hide the list value based on the login.When **Superadmin** login show the **city** list .But **user** login hide the **city** list.

Here is **controller.js**

```
  myAppControllers.controller('LoginController',['$scope', '$location', '$http', 
function($scope, $location, $http) {

    $scope.log_userx = {};

    $scope.login_user = function(login) {
    $scope.log_user = angular.copy(login);    
    $scope.login = {};                                  
    $http({
        url: "/login",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data:$scope.log_user
    }).success(function (data) {
        var resp = data['user']
        $scope.user_admin = data.user.roles;
        $location.path("/index");
    }).error(function (data,status) {
        $location.path("/login");
    });
    $scope.finduser=function(){
    $scope.user_admin1=$scope.user_admin;
    alert(angular.toJson("admin1 "+$scope.user_admin1));
     $scope.visible = false;
     if($scope.user_admin1!=="superadmin")
     {
     alert("Not Superadmin");
     $scope.visible =true;
     return $scope.visible;
     }
    return true;
    };
};}]);
```

In Html file

```
        <ul class="breadcrumb" style="background-color:#EEEEEE" ng-init="finduser()">
            <li><button type="submit" id="datadash" class="btn btn-default">home</button></li>
            <li ng-if="visible==true"><a href="/#/city" class="button special">city</a></li>            

</div>
```

Comment: Just give ng-if="visible" and check if its working.. Also once check by printing visible value using {{visible}}. Just to make sure you are getting the value you are looking for

Comment: Take note that ng-if creates its own scope and visible is not anymore connected with your controller. ng-show might solve your issue, or use controllerAs syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update scope with both if and else condition.

```
if($scope.user_admin1!=="superadmin")
 {
 alert("Not Superadmin");
 $scope.visible =true;
// return $scope.visible;
 }else{
$scope.visible =false;
}
```

and change the HTML as below.

```
<li ng-if="visible"><a href="/#/city" class="button special">city</a></li>
```

Comment: i didn't get alert and not working..the city is not showing in both login

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this html by changing the condition of viewing the city list.

```
<ul class="breadcrumb" style="background-color:#EEEEEE" ng-init="finduser()">
        <li><button type="submit" id="datadash" class="btn btn-default">home</button></li>
        <li ng-if="!visible"><a href="/#/city" class="button special">city</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-show for this.

```
<li ng-show="visible==true"><a href="/#/city" class="button special">city</a></li>
```

With this only "city" link shall appear only for your superadmin.

Showing this superadmin link is a part of animation based on $scope values at controller.js level whereas ng-if uses the $animate service when there is animation on the html to html inputs exclusing controller.js. Here is example for [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) and [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) from angular docs

Comment: Showing this superadmin link is a part of animation based on $scope values at controller.js level whereas ng-if uses the $animate service when there is animation on the html to html inputs exclusing controller.js. Here is example for [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) and [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) from angular docs

Comment: Ok.. So if we want something to be animated, we need to go with ng-if.. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: You can use ng-if for animations among many other things. However for this case the animation is based on $scope value so recommend ng-show. We could have used ng-if it the superadmin value was provided by some checkbox or radio on same html page.